# What encoding is used when calling an Oracle PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, coldfusion, character-encoding, coldfusion-9

On my coldfusion page I call a PL/SQL procedure. The HTML form is encoded using UTF-8, the oracle DB has the encoding `WE8ISO8859P1`. So what kind of conversion happens in the case of `i_value` below?

I'm especially interested in what happens to MS Word left quote (which is encoded in UTF-8 as `E28098`). When I decode `i_value` in PL/SQL this becomes `18`(Hex). Considering that it is U+2018 this makes some sense, but I still wonder why the `20` is swallowed.

```
<CFSTOREDPROC PROCEDURE = "my_schema.lib.write_field" datasource="#datasource#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" variable="i_name"   value="remark"  type="In">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" variable="i_value" value="#Form.remark#" type="In">
</CFSTOREDPROC>
```

Comment: I'm not a CF expert, so no answer, only a comment: Every client environment (and your CF is a client to your Oracle DB) connecting to an Oracle DB uses a NLS_LANG env. variable to determine the client charset to be used for Oracle DB connections. So, there's one charset set up at your Oracle DB side (WE8ISO8859P1), second one at your HTML page (UTF8), third one at your ColdFusion server, I presume, and there is, most probably, a fourth one set up for the Oracle client in use in your CF server. I assume you'll have to find that particular option and set it up to e.g. ENGLISH_AMERICA.AL32UTF8.

Comment: The NLS_LANG variable, of course, can be exchanged for some kind of a dedicated parameter in your Oracle DB connection. (ODP.NET does so, if I remember correctly.) Still, my comment applies - you'll have to find that DB connection property and set it up.

Comment: @nop77svk Even after knowing the client encoding, I would like to know what kind of conversion happens. I noticed that some of the bytes just seem to get swallowed when sent to the DB, e.g. the left single quotation mark (0x2018 in UTF-16) becomes just 0x18 in the DB.

Comment: Aaa, this is what you mean! Well, conversion in Oracle is driven by the nice files in the `${ORACLE_HOME}/nls` folder, afaik. But I can't tell you how exactly.

Comment: @nop77svk From the example I gave it seems that the most significant byte is just ignored and only the least significant byte is considered.

Comment: Still, I don't know. If I were you and if I had a full control over all app tiers, I'd play around with `nvarchar2` strings, maybe, and debug the conversions separately on app. tier per tier basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ColdFusion is Java based so I guess the string variables are encoded using UTF-16.

When going from `UTF-16`(2 byte encoding) to a 1 byte encoding(e.g. `WE8ISO8859P1`) as is the case in my example, the MSB is ignored and only the LSB is considered.

This would explain the observed behavior:
I noticed that some of the bytes just seem to get swallowed when sent to the DB, e.g. the [left single quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm) (0x2018 in UTF-16) becomes just 0x18 in the DB.